# Way of replacing CStr with other function

Tags: vb6

I must build an equation which performs on a database in IDEA SmartAnalyzer, so all the functions used must have a **@** in their name.

For example, this is the equation I must build:

```
For Each vValue In vList
    i = i + 1
    If i = 1 Then 
        sCriticalText = "\b" & CStr(vValue) & "\b"
    Else 
        sCriticalText = sCriticalText & "|\b" & CStr(vValue) & "\b"
    End If
Next
```

What I must do is to replace the `CStr()` function with one compatible with IDEA. 
Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Try removing it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean must **not** have a @ in their name?

If so use

```
Replace(CStr(vValue), "@", vbNullString)
```